# Setting width/height of unknown images for lazy loading

Tags: javascript, web-development, html, css, typescript

I have a site where users upload images & can all be viewed on a single page by other users. I want to lazy load images as the user scrolls instead of loading all initially. This is easy enough, but relies on a width/height being set for the images used in calculating if the image is coming close to the viewport. This part is difficult since I have zero idea what the image sizing is before loading it. I only have a URL saved to insert into the `src` attribute of an `img` tag. I want to keep the aspect ratio of the picture intact.

I don't want lots of empty space. I can set a parent div to be 500x500 pixels & use CSS like `object-fit` or `max-width` / `max-height` to make sure the img has the right aspect ratio within the 500x500 box...but this often results in lots of wasted space & poor looking UI. Portrait images will have wide left & right gutters for instance while landscape will have wide top & bottom gutters.

I've searched & cannot find solutions of others although many people have to have had this issue. The only solution I can think of is to save aspect ratio meta data when an image is uploaded....somehow derive this information from a `File` type in Typescript if possible. Then, instead of only fetching a list of URLs, I'll also fetch this aspect ratio which I can use to hardcode the size of the image BEFORE I've loaded it. This requires major changes to my site...does this seem feasible & an appropriate approach to solving this?

I inspected photos.google.com & it seems they are somehow manually calculating each pictures deminsions. They use specific width/height pixels vs. general CSS properties like `object-fit` or `max-height` / `max-width`

Comment: In typical image store designs, the width and height are saved as part of the metadata associated with the urls. Having just the width and height available will save a lot of trouble. In certain designs, the images are further post-processed (after upload) to identify a crop rectangle, one that highlights the most interesting section of the image. That way, the website is in control of the aspect ratio, irrespective of the image's original aspect ratio. The mechanism for detecting "the most interesting section of the image" may require some AI.

Comment: If possible (i.e. if you have the mechanism to extract the width and height of newly uploaded images), you can encode that information into the newly created URL.

Comment: The code for determining the width and height of an image file (without spending time on fully decoding the picture) involves reading the first 1-2 kilobytes of data. Sometimes it can be decoded with just a few dozens of bytes. Each image format requires a different piece of detection code. It can be done without depending on a third-party library, as long as the first few kilobytes of raw file data can be accessed.

Comment: TIFF is an image format where this (use simple code to determine width and height after looking at the first 1-2 KB) is not guaranteed. However, few websites allow users to upload TIFF images.

Comment: This is good insight, thank you, seems it is typical to manually save aspect ratio meta data

Comment: We implemented fast size determination reading the initial bytes of images for JPEG, PNG and TIFF files. I cannot publish the code (and it is not Javascript), but the information is all available in public.

Comment: I need it to be processed client side using JS. Will have to read specs about image file structure it seems, not much publicly around parsing that info client side that I can find.

Comment: @AveryFerrante why do you need to do it client-side? Don't you control the server side? Relying on the client telling you the truth isn't always safe.

Comment: Many CDNs have serverless image handlers as a service. Example ... https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/serverless-image-handler/

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner I don't control the server side much. I'm using Google's Firebase services which is basically "back end as a service". I have access to running Node.js in anonymous function style (like lambda AWS or functions in Azure). Client side would make everything so much easier.

Can't use a CDN. Reading EXIF data on a per-basis image file type (png, jpg, jpeg, etc.) seems cumbersome...seems there isn't a "supported" way to achieve this in client-side JS...have to read byte data

Comment: I found this ... is it relevant? 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#execute_intensive_tasks_in_the_cloud_instead_of_in_your_app , also https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/imagemagick

Comment: Here is a [starter in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111345/getting-image-dimensions-without-reading-the-entire-file). Port this to JS.